# Using AODV in a wired simulation

Tags: omnet++, inet

I am trying to use AODV in a wired simulation but I can't make it work, is it possible to link 2 AODVRouters by wire and use the AODV protocol?? or should I use 2 standardhost and modify the AODVrouting.cc??

EDIT:
I just simulate the AODV simpleRREQ example using standardhosts instead of AODVrouters and using the debug mode it crashes in this piece of code:

```
void AODVRouting::sendAODVPacket(AODVControlPacket *packet, const L3Address& destAddr, unsigned int timeToLive, double delay)
{INetworkProtocolControlInfo *networkProtocolControlInfo = addressType->createNetworkProtocolControlInfo();

networkProtocolControlInfo->setHopLimit(timeToLive);

networkProtocolControlInfo->setTransportProtocol(IP_PROT_MANET);
networkProtocolControlInfo->setDestinationAddress(destAddr);
networkProtocolControlInfo->setSourceAddress(getSelfIPAddress());

// TODO: Implement: support for multiple interfaces

InterfaceEntry *ifEntry = interfaceTable->getInterfaceByName("AODV");
networkProtocolControlInfo->setInterfaceId(ifEntry->getInterfaceId());

UDPPacket *udpPacket = new UDPPacket(packet->getName());
udpPacket->encapsulate(packet);
udpPacket->setSourcePort(aodvUDPPort);
udpPacket->setDestinationPort(aodvUDPPort);
udpPacket->setControlInfo(dynamic_cast<cObject *>(networkProtocolControlInfo));

if (destAddr.isBroadcast())
    lastBroadcastTime = simTime();

if (delay == 0)
    send(udpPacket, "ipOut");
else
    sendDelayed(udpPacket, delay, "ipOut");
}
```

How can I send the AODV packet throw all the ethernet ports of the router?

Comment: Just curious, why do you want to use a wireless ad hoc routing protocol in wired networks with fixed connections? Or do you want to bridge between two wireless networks?

Comment: I am trying to implement AODV in a wired net where you don´t know where are the other nodes or if they are even connected. I need to broadcast RREQs through the net to find them like AODV does in wireless.

Comment: Why not use one of the many (wired) routing protocols like Open Shortest Path First? What does AODV provide that others (already working ones) do not have? What's so special about your scenario that you really require AODV? Maybe I don't see it...

Comment: My objetive is implement LOADng (an AODV modification) to find routes in tension lines where the conexions can be lost like in a wireless situation.

Comment: So what specific error did occur? Did you try to use wireless hosts and put a "cable" connection between them? Some additional information might help to understand what you've already did and what errors occurred.

Comment: I found that the InterfaceEntry is what crashes the simulation

Comment: Maybe add your "fix" as your own answer so that people know how you solved things!

Comment: I found the problem, not the solution yet.